# identify invalid data and report these to the user via messages on the console

Tags: java

****I need solution for this input file****

Requirement

The data stored in the file could be corrupted. For this requirement, the program must examine each line of data read from the file, identify invalid data and report these to the user via messages on the console.  At a minimum, the program should check and validate the following possible issues–

- The home team name may be missing.
- The away team name may be missing.
- The home team score may be missing.
- The away team score may be missing.
- The field delimiter may be missing or wrong field delimiter is used.
- Home team score may not be a valid integer number.
- Away team score may not be a valid integer number.

The sample input file is:

```
Aston Villa : Middlesbrough : 3 : 1
Chelsea : Manchester City : 1 // only 3 fields provided
Tottenham Hotspur : Stoke City : 0 : 0
Hull : : 2 : 3 // missing away team name
West Ham United : Wigan Athletic : 2 : 1
: : 2 : 0 // both team names missing
Fulham : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Arsenal Liverpool : 2 : 2 // missing delimiter (:) between teams
Sunderland : Newcastle United : 0 : 4
Hull : Liverpool : 5 : x // ‘x’ given instead of away team score
```

Comment: @happybent. Can you provide what you tried till now and more explanation for invalid data. I am not sure which data is invalid here until we did not get the your proper requirement.

Comment: This is not a question, it’s a cheap attempt to make us do OP’s homework and should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            if(s.trim().isEmpty()) break;
            try {
                String parts[] = s.split(":");
                if(parts.length != 4 || parts[0].trim().length() == 0 || parts[1].trim().length() == 0) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                Integer.parseInt(parts[2].trim());
                Integer.parseInt(parts[3].trim());
                System.out.println("valid");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @happydent Please figure it out yourself.